# React Virtualized Table cellRenderer onClick method issue

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using react-virtualized for data table and I am having this issue. My goal is to attach `onClick` method to the cells.

I have `renderColumns` function inside `<Table>`

```
<AutoSizer disableHeight>
  {({ width }) => (
    <Table
       width={800}
       height={600}
       headerHeight={25}
       rowHeight={30}
       rowCount={list.length}
       rowGetter={({ index }) => list[index]}
    >
       {this._renderColumns(list, 100)}

    </Table>
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

And in `renderColumns` function, I call `this._cellRenderer`

```
_renderColumns(list, columnWidth) {
// create new list for display
return list && Object.keys(list[0])
  ? Object.keys(list[0]).map(column => (
      <Column
        key={column}
        width={columnWidth}
        label={column}
        dataKey={column}
        cellRenderer={this._cellRenderer}
      />
    ))
  : <div className="loading">Loading…</div>;
```

}

Then in `_cellRenderer`, I tried to call `_onCellClick` on `onClick` event.

```
_onCellClick() {
  alert('yey');
}

_cellRenderer({
  cellData,
  columnData,
  columnIndex,
  dataKey,
  isScrolling,
  rowData,
  rowIndex,
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={this._onCellClick}>{cellData}</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I do that, I get TypeError: Cannot read property '_onCellClick' of undefined error. So it's telling me that `this` is undefined in this scope? What am I doing wrong?

I've created a sample here. Thank you.

[image: Edit Z6Vo1g5zR]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to bind _cellRenderer as you have bound the other two methods to use it in this way.  You're just passing a function as a prop to the table.... if it's not bound there will be no 'this' since classes are always in strict mode.

Comment: That was it. `this` always trips me. Thank you so much!